# Android App Unintentionally Restarting Tablet

Tags: android, opengl-es, bluetooth, tablet, min3d

I'm working with a SM-t230NU andorid tablet. We have an android application running on it that is quite simple. All it does is find/verify Bluetooth a connection, collects data, displays it and does a fairly simple GUI(in min3d) off of the data. The problem is that on very rare occasion, after a long time of running the entire tablet just restarts. No warnings, no prompts.

We have had multiple versions of this demo all of the other were stable on the variety of phones that we have. I'm currently running tests on multiple phones and the tablet. I'm running old versions of the app on the tablet, while I try the new app on phones.

I'm honestly suspecting that something is wrong with our tablet. That said I hate blaming hardware. Is it even possible for an android app to crash the whole OS?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you.

EDIT*
I caught a stack trace. The restart occured at 14:07

```
02-26 14:06:18.050: D/dalvikvm(17266): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-26 14:06:18.290: W/initializeBluetooth(17266): Initialize Called
02-26 14:06:18.300: E/BluetoothHeadset(17266): BTStateChangeCB is registed
02-26 14:06:18.300: E/BluetoothHeadset(17266): BluetoothHeadset service is inded
02-26 14:06:18.360: W/Bluetooth Connect(17266): No Connected Device Found
02-26 14:07:10.260: W/System.err(17266): android.os.DeadObjectException
02-26 14:07:10.270: W/System.err(17266): at adroid.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
02-26 14:07:10.270: W/System.err(17266): at com.samsung.android.multiwindow.IMultiWindowFacade$Stub$Proxy.getMultiWindowStyle(IMultiWindowFacade.java:475)
02-26 14:07:10.270: W/System.err(17266): at com.samsung.android.multiwindow.MultiWindowFacade.getMultiWindowStyle(MultiWindowFacade.java:57)
02-26 14:07:10.270: W/System.err(17266): at android.app.Activity.getMultiWindowStyle(Activity.java:4565)
02-26 14:07:10.270: W/System.err(17266): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1676)
02-26 14:07:10.270: W/System.err(17266): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
02-26 14:07:10.270: W/System.err(17266): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6529)
02-26 14:07:10.270: W/System.err(17266): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:812)
02-26 14:07:10.270: W/System.err(17266): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:612)
02-26 14:07:10.270: W/System.err(17266): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582)
02-26 14:07:10.270: W/System.err(17266): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:798)
02-26 14:07:10.281: W/System.err(17266): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-26 14:07:10.281: W/System.err(17266): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-26 14:07:10.281: W/System.err(17266): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
02-26 14:07:10.281: W/System.err(17266): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
02-26 14:07:10.281: W/System.err(17266): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 14:07:10.291: W/System.err(17266): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-26 14:07:10.291: W/System.err(17266): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
02-26 14:07:10.291: W/System.err(17266): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
02-26 14:07:10.291: W/System.err(17266): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 14:07:10.311: D/GC(17266): <tid=17266> veglGetDisplayBackBuffer, can't dequeuebuffer from nativeWindow = 0x77964380!
02-26 14:07:10.311: D/v_gal(17266): [tid=17266] _SwapBuffersRegion(1238): Get back buffer failed
02-26 14:07:10.311: W/HardwareRenderer(17266): EGL error: EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW
```

Comment: So far we have had multiple phones running just fine for 3-4 hours now. Usually a crash happens once ever hour or so. The tablet has also not crashed yet.

Comment: If there is a better way to display a stack trace please let me know.

Comment: "does a fairly simple GUI(in min3d)". This statement seems contradictory. min3D is not for simple GUIs. You may want to go through these course videos by Colt https://www.udacity.com/courses/ud825 (to access the course materials for free, you'll need to login, but do not click on the free trial otherwise it will ask you for a credit card number). Also, you may want to go to Settings > Display > and uncheck Multi-window (but this is just a stab in the dark).

Answer (score 0):

My phone, Samsung Galaxy S4 has almost full memory, I can't update my applications due to lack of storage.

2 of the Applications I'm currently working on has GoogleMaps integration. Both applications literally freeze my phone when I try to lunch the MapActivities. I have to pull the battery out so that I can restart the phone.

I suggest monitoring the memory consumption, CPU status periodically. Maybe start a service which writes this kind of data to a file periodically and read from it.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable next steps. I'll get back to you.

Comment: We are deffinitly not using up too much CPU or memory. I've confirmed all seems normal on that front. Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Should have figured this out sooner. The stack trace has zero calls to any of our Java files. Our code was exacerbating an issue internal to the device itself. After a factory reset everything functioned as expected.